# How to set value inside image tag dynamically in a loop using PHP and my sql

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help.I need to set some DB value dynamically(`i.e-image,class`) inside a `li` element using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
<ul class="sequence-canvas">
  <li class="animate-in">
    <div class="intro">
      <h2>My Discount Pharmacy //set title from db</h2>
      <h3>
We are an end to end healthcare service provider where the doctors can enter their prescriptions, patients can upload their prescriptions. //set subtitle
      </h3>
    </div>
    <img class="iphone" src="img/seq-slider/iphone.png" alt="iPhone4" /> //set image1 from DB
    <img class="iphone-shadow" src="img/seq-slider/iphone-shadow.png" alt="" /> //set image2 from DB
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="ipad" src="img/seq-slider/ipad.png" alt="iPad" />//set image1 from DB
    <div class="slide2">
      <h2>My Discount Pharmacy // set title from DB</h2>
      <p>
We are an end to end healthcare service provider where the doctors can enter their prescriptions, patients can upload their prescriptions. //Set subtitle from DB.
      </p>
    </div>
    <img class="ipad-shadow" src="img/seq-slider/ipad-shadow.png" alt="" />  //set image2 from DB
  </li>
</ul>
```

From the above code i need to iterate each set of `li` element in a loop and set some value dynamically.I am explaining my php code below.

```
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("select * from phr_news order by news_id desc");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $subtitle = $row['sub_title'];
    $image1 = $row['image1'];
    $image2 = $row['image2'];
}
?>
```

Here i need to iterate each `li` element inside loop and set the above values in proper place.Please help me.

Comment: what actually stored in image1 and image2? image in blob? image name ? or image path?

Comment: image path. it should be available like `uploads/image1.png` like this.

Comment: yes like above.but Please read my post again.

Comment: **Don't use `mysql_*` functions**, they are deprecated and rather dangerous in the wrong hands: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will helps you to getting the desired output

```
<?php 
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from phr_news order by news_id desc");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ ?><li class="animate-in">
        <div class="intro">
          <h2>
            <?php $row['title']; ?> //set title from db
          </h2>
          <h3>
            <?php $row['sub_title']; ?> //set subtitle
          </h3>
        </div>
        <img class="iphone" src="img/seq-slider/<?php $row['image1']; ?>" alt="iPhone4" /> //set image1 from DB
        <img class="iphone-shadow" src="img/seq-slider/<?php $row['image2']; ?>" alt="" /> //set image2 from DB
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="ipad" src="img/seq-slider/<?php $row['image1']; ?>" alt="iPad" />//set image1 from DB
        <div class="slide2">
          <h2>
            <?php $row['title']; ?> // set title from DB
          </h2>
          <p>
            We are an end to end healthcare service provider where the doctors can enter their prescriptions, patients can upload their prescriptions. //Set subtitle from DB.
          </p>
        </div>
        <img class="ipad-shadow" src="img/seq-slider/<?php $row['image2']; ?>" alt="" />  //set image2 from DB
      </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how you could do it (not tested though):

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from phr_news order by news_id desc");

echo '<ul class="sequence-canvas">' . PHP_EOL;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    echo '<li class="animate-in">
        <div class="intro">
          <h2>' . $row['title'] . '</h2>
          <h3>' . $row['sub_title'] . '</h3>
        </div>
        <img class="iphone" src="' . $row['image1'] . '" alt="iPhone4" />
        <img class="iphone-shadow" src="' . $row['image2'] . 'alt="" />
      </li>
';
    echo '<li>
        <img class="ipad" src="' . $row['image1'] . '" alt="iPad" />
        <div class="slide2">
          <h2>' . $row['sub_title'] . '</h2>
          <p>' . $row['sub_title'] . '</p>
        </div>
        <img class="ipad-shadow" src="' . $row['image2'] . ' alt="" />
      </li>
';
} // end while
echo '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: To be honest, this is easier to work with if you don't `echo` the HTML, but simply intersperse it outside a `php` block. The HTML will be formatted correctly by your editor, making it a lot easier on the eyes (compared to the giant blob of string it would be now). Then you could use shorthand to echo the values like `<?=$row['sub_title']?>` - I think that would look a lot cleaner.

Comment: I accept your comment as a valuable alternative. On  the other side I am not really conviced that despersed echo statements like this <?php echo this; ?><html_tag>...</html_tag><?php  =that; ?>... makes the code cleaner and better readable (?)

Comment: Ah that's why I mentioned the shorthand: `<?=$var?>`, which is a little more legible (it's mentioned on PHPs `echo` docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). I mostly suggest it in this case because _most_ of the code here is HTML, therefor I think this would be more legible with the HTML as intact as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, this is how you should do it.

your php code

```
<?php 
     $phr_news = array();
     $sql=mysql_query("select * from phr_news order by news_id desc");
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        array_push("title" => $row['title'], 
                   "subtitle" => $row['sub_title'], 
                   "image1" => $row['image1'], 
                   "image2" => $row['image2']
        );
     }
?>
```

and here is the view html

```
<ul class="sequence-canvas">
        <?php foreach ($phr_news  => $phr_new): ?>
            <li class="animate-in">
              <div class="intro">
                <h2>
                  <?php echo $phr_new['title'] ?>
                </h2>
                <h3>
                  <?php echo $phr_new['subtitle'] ?>
                </h3>
              </div>
              <img class="iphone" src="<?php echo $phr_new['image1'] ?>" alt="iPhone4" /> 
              <img class="iphone-shadow" src="<?php echo $phr_new['image2'] ?>" alt="" /> 
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Maybe this would work: _array\_push(**$phr_new,** "title" => $row['title']); array\_push( ...);_ ...**

Comment: ooh, your right @hherger i forgort the array itself

Comment: @tonypro : Please check my post again there is some difference of class name in each set of `li` element so when it will come in a loop as per you how it will reflect.

Comment: Okay, if your code just need two <li> tags you can use a for loop like so: `for(i=o;  i<count($phr_news); i++){  if(i==o) { the code for the first li tag elseif i==1 then: the code for the second li tag  } }` i think that this may work but the entire approach is not optimal